# How to attach additional properties for the jQuery Autocomplete select event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-1.7

My current code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtSearchForTrainingFacility').autocomplete({
        select: function (event, ui) {
                    searchCallback(event, ui);
                },      //  select
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:49795/Ajax/Search/' + $('#txtSearchForTrainingFacility').val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Name,
                            value: item.Value,
                            id: item.ID
                        }   //  return object
                    }))     //  response
                }           //  success
            })              //  ajax
        }                   //  source function
    });                     //  autocomplete
});                         //  document.ready
```

You can see that in the `ajax.success` event function I am mapping returning an object with `label`, `value`, and `id` properties - yet the `autocomplete.select` method's `ui.item` parameter only contains `label` and `value`.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the `id` property to appear on the `autocomplete.select`'s `ui.item` object?

> the result of the ajax call is a json array, with each element an object that contains the properties `Name`, `Value`, and `ID`.

**Note**
If you replace the ajax call with a fixed array `[{id: 1, label: 'bob', value: 'creep'}, {id: 2, label: 'joe', value: 'friend'}]` then the `id` property seem to come through in the select event just fine.

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI and jQuery you use?

Comment: jQuery 1.7.1, and jQueryUI 1.8.20 - the versions that come default with ASP.NET MVC 4.  I have a lot of existing code using these versions.  If I have to change, I'd prefer a change to a version that is compatible with these.

Comment: Is this something you can recreate at a code sample/sharing site like [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Also, have you confirmed that your ../Ajax/Search/{search term} web service is in fact returning a JSON object with an ID value set?

Comment: @Dan-o, Check using `console.log(data)` in your `success` function if there is an `ID` (not `id`) available.

Comment: @Dan-o: It would be practical if you append your question with **exact JSON response returned from the server**. You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Developer Tools of IE, Chrome or Firefox to catch the exact HTTP traffic. Having the test data one could reproduce the problem and debug the code.

Comment: @Dan-o provide exact output what you want this seems thaty you want to show id in autocomplete li is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the jQuery UI 1.8.20 source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/8226f9f02c4d88885f2df8dde1996eaf9dd6f270/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L169), the item object is stored directly in the `<li>` using jQuery `data()`.  The only place in jQuery UI where the object could be changed between your `response` callback and the storage of the object as `data` is in [the `_normalize` private function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/8226f9f02c4d88885f2df8dde1996eaf9dd6f270/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L344).  It will explicitly keep only the label and the value if the object you're passing is a string, but otherwise even the `_normalize` function should keep your object intact.

This, and the fact that passing a static array solves your issue, leads me to believe that your problem lies in the JSON coming from your server, and not the JavaScript snippet you posted.  Your code assumes the default `ID` field from your ASP.NET server; it might be worthwhile double-checking to make sure that you still have that field name as your default.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put all attribs in lower case, and map like this :

```
response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.value,
        id: item.id
    }   //  return object
}));    //  response
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution ! Refer this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Wz7Vy/) demo**

**Inspect the list items using firebug and you will be able to see the underlying structure**. The function `_renderItem()` will be useful for you ! By using this function **you can customize each and every list item**. For further reference refer this link :
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem

Answer (score 0):

On your source-request page you should put your record in an array called "id", "label" and "value" as you've described. You can also create another if you need it called [description] (if necessary)

to return your array to the AJAX use **serializeJSON(returnArray)**

there is my example.

```
function split(val){
      return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term){
      return split(term).pop();
}

$("#example").autocomplete({

     source: function(request, response){
          $.getJSON('http://localhost:49795/Ajax/Search.php', {
               term: extractLast(request.term)
          }, response);
     },

     search: function(){
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast(this.value);
          if (term.length < 2) {
               return false;
           }
      },

      focus: function(){
           // prevent value inserted on focus
           return false;
      },

      select: function(event, ui){
           this.value = terms.push(ui.item.id);
           return false;
       }

});
```

This is how I'm doing this and in my case it works. Maybe there is some unnecessary lines but if you want you can change it as you wish :)